# how to create data factory's integrated runtime in arm template

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to deploy data factory using ARM template. It is easy to use the exported template to create a deployment pipeline.

However, as the data factory needs to access an on-premise database server, I need to have an integrated runtime. The problem is how can I include the run time in the arm template?

The template looks like this and we can see that it is trying to include the runtime:

```
{
    "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/OnPremisesSqlServer')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
    "properties": 
    {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "SqlServer",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": "[parameters('OnPremisesSqlServer_connectionString')]"
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "OnPremisesSqlServer",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/integrationRuntimes/OnPremisesSqlServer')]"
    ]
},
{
    "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/OnPremisesSqlServer')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes",
    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
    "properties": {
        "type": "SelfHosted",
        "typeProperties": {}
    },
    "dependsOn": []
}
```

Running this template gives me this error:

```
\"connectVia\": {\r\n      \"referenceName\": \"OnPremisesSqlServer\",\r\n      \"type\": \"IntegrationRuntimeReference\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n} and error is: Failed to encrypted linked service credentials on self-hosted IR 'OnPremisesSqlServer', reason is: NotFound, error message is: No online instance..
```

The problem is that I will need to type in some key in the integrated runtime's UI, so it can be registered in azure. But I  can only get that key from my data factory instance's UI. So above arm template deployment will always fail at least once. I am wondering if there is a way to create the run time independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I will need to type in some key in the integrated
>   runtime's UI, so it can be registered in azure. But I can only get
>   that key from my data factory instance's UI. So above arm template
>   deployment will always fail at least once. I am wondering if there is
>   a way to create the run time independently?

It seems that you already know how to create [Self-Hosted IR in the ADF ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/2018-06-01/factories/integrationruntimes#IntegrationRuntime).

```
{
          "name": "[concat(parameters('dataFactoryName'), '/integrationRuntime1')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes",
          "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
          "properties": {
            "additionalProperties": {},
            "description": "jaygongIR1",
            "type": "SelfHosted"
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Only you concern is that [Windows IR Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717) need to be configured with `AUTHENTICATION KEY` to access ADF Self-Hosted IR node.So,it should be `Unavailable` status once it is created.This flow is make sense i think,authenticate key should be created first,then you can use it to configure On-Premise Tool.You can't implement all of things in one step because these behaviors are operated on both of azure and on-premise sides.

Based on the [Self-Hosted IR Tool document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#install-and-register-a-self-hosted-ir-from-microsoft-download-center) ,the Register steps can't be implemented with Powershell code. So,all steps can't be processed in the flow are creating IR and getting Auth key,not for Registering in the tool.

Comment: Hi, @jay Gong, not sure I understand you. Are you saying it is not possible to include register step in arm template, so I just need to run pipeline twice?

Comment: @daxu Yes,exactly. Create IR-->Generate Auth key--> Configure on-premise tool --> Sync that node with IR. Can't be finished in one step.